# Apache (WAMP) taking forever if accessed other than by localhost

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp

I have WAMP on Windows XP, and the Apache server runs just fine if I access the content via localhost.

I followed this guide to set up access from other clients:
http://www.petri.co.il/install_wamp_server_on_vista.htm

So, I opened port 80 in my router to forward requests to Apache. Went to www.whatismyip.com to see where to point my browser. The server is actually hit, but takes forever to load content and the browser eventually gives up.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most ISP's block incoming port 80 so that people do not do exactly what you are trying to do.  Try using a non-standard port (8080, 888, etc.) and see if you have any better luck that way.